# Pycharm error "No Python interpreter configured for the project" on mac, although conda path provided

Tags: python, pycharm, anaconda

[image: default settings]I have installed conda on my mac and have been using conda mainly. Recently I switched to Pycharm. Although I went to Pycharm default settings and point python 3.6 interpreter path (came from "which python"), everytime I open a new python program in Pycharm, it keeps saying "No Python interpreter configured for the project" until I go and edit it again to point to this path. This is very annoying.

dca90498c361:~ xxx$ which python
/anaconda3/bin/python[default settings[image: ][1]]

Comment: Make sure there's no `.idea/` alongside `functions.py`, this options works only for new projects. Which PyCharm version is this?

Comment: the version is 2017.1.2

Answer (score 0):

It seems there was a bug with Pycharm version 17.1.2. When I upgraded to 18.2, this is gone! Thanks for your help Pavel